# Why my program can not resolve symbol 'Builder' in my material dialog method

Tags: java, android, dialog

I am trying to make a material dialog in android 10 that asks to get pictures from either the camera or a gallery.
I have these two issues in my method:  can not resolve symbol 'Builder'  and can not resolve symbol 'ListCallback'. How can I sort these issues?

I have two strings arrays: string-array name="uploadImages" and string-array name="itemIds" in the value folder.

I am still stuck here......This is what I have done

I was trying to find this problem for myself all this time but I still don't find my solution to the error.
 It is not a compiler error, I get it when writing the method.
I have loaded all the dependencies from https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs and still getting the 
error ' cannot resolve symbol(builder). MaterialDialogs.Builder(this) '  and  'cannot resolve symbol(ListCallback())'.

If I use  minSdkVersion 19 and  targetSdkVersion 26  it works fine.
But in this versions   ''minSdkVersion 21 to  targetSdkVersion 29 '' it does not work. I cannot
really figure this out.  I appreciate your help.  Thanks

Here is the code:

```java
public void onClick(final View view) 
{ 
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.pick_image:
                         new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                       .title(R.string.uploadImages)
                       .items(R.array.uploadImages)
                       .itemsIds(R.array.itemIds)
                       .itemsCallback(new MaterialDialog.ListCallback() {

                            public void onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                                switch (which){
                                    case 0:
                                        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                                        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                                        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
                                        break;
                                    case 1:
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_PHOTO);
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        profileImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.jetplane);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        })
             .show();

                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Are both mentioned issues compiler-errors? Then: Please mark the code-lines with comments or add the error-outputs.

Comment: You will need to import the fully qualified name of MaterialDialog.Builder and MaterialDialog.ListCallback if you confirm that they do exist and usable from 'outside'

Comment: ok, I will do the full MaterialDialog import and see if it works. tks

Answer (score 1):

this late but anyways

add this in Build gradle app module and remove all other implementation related to com.afollestad.material

implementation group: 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs', name: 'commons', version: '0.9.6.0'